# How to record the in game content on iOS and save it

Tags: ios, video, screen, capture

My daughters have an iOS game called Princess story from Disney. In the game, they place characters on a background. Then they can hit a record button and it records their voices while also recording them moving the characters they placed on the screen.

They have another game that does the same thing called Breitville. This game even saves the video to the camera roll.

I have searched and searched on how they are doing this and have come up empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Comment: You wouldn't think this would be such a hard request. I can't find any information. I see it in many games, so I'm surprised someone has not made a tutorial or something on capturing a video of the screen.

Comment: Knowing the relevant class name from my link above, you can google "AVCaptureSession example tutorial", there's plenty of them.